# How to stream documents from a collection in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream

I have this:

```
d.db(dbName)
     .collection(dbCollName)
     .find()
     .sort({_id: 1})
     .limit(5000).stream()
```

this expression returns this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

basically all I am trying to do is instead of this:

```
   d.db(dbName)
         .collection(dbCollName)
         .find()
         .sort({_id: 1})
         .limit(5000).toArray().then(console.log);
```

I instead want to stream the documents one-by-one etc, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes mongodb **`cursor`** that is returned by **`db.collection().find()`** does have a **[`stream() api`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Cursor.html#stream)** to stream the documents:

```
const stream = db
  .collection("dbCollName")
  .find()
  .stream();

stream.on("data", function(data) {
  //get streamed documents one by one
  const currentDoc = data;
});

stream.on("error", function(error) {
  console.error("STREAM ERROR::", error.stack);
});

stream.on("end", function() {
  console.info("Streaming docs finished");
  client.close(); //new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
});
```

Sometime back wrote a demo test for `stream` with `mongodb node driver` cursor to clone a collection for a fair amount of dataset. **[some more info](https://github.com/ambianBeing/mongo-stream-demo/blob/master/index.js)**